# 顔画像から輪郭部分だけを抽出し画像化する方法

Tags: 画像

[image: 顔画像の正規化]

上の図(あくまで例で、これと同じ方式でやりたいというわけではありません)のように、顔画像から頭髪を含まない輪郭部分だけ抽出して画像化するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか
言語はPythonかC++だと都合がいいです。画像はhttp://www.intechopen.com/books/ne‌​w-approaches-to-char‌​acterization-and-rec‌​ognition-of-faces/re‌​al-time-video-face-r‌​ecognition-for-embed‌​ded-devicesからの引用です。用‌​途としては大量の画像を自動的に処理するこ‌​とが目的です。

Opencvの顔認識を使って特徴点から輪郭を切り取るなどを考えたのですが、具体的にどうすれば実装できるのか教えてくださると助かります

Comment: 「ライブラリを教えて」と記載されていますが言語は一体ドチラになるのでしょうか？また、使用するための条件もよく分かりません。

Comment: 引用されている画像は[こちらの書籍](http://www.intechopen.com/books/new-approaches-to-characterization-and-recognition-of-faces/real-time-video-face-recognition-for-embedded-devices)の Figure 3 です。書籍中ではこの画像はCorcoranらの2006年の論文で使われている手法の例だと書かれていますが、この論文には当たってみましたか？ それとも、単に例としてこの画像を用いているだけで、とりあえずどんな方法でもいいから試してみたいという話でしょうか。

Comment: 画像は例で、輪郭から顔を切り取る方法を試してみたいと思っています

Comment: 参考： 本家StackOverflowに、輪郭ではなくて頭部全体を抽出するにはどうすればよいか？という質問がありました。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967284/opencv-human-head-not-just-face-extraction-from-photographs

Answer (score 0):

使用シーンがよくわからないのでOpenCVで用途に合わせて使用してくださいとまでしか言えないですね・・・

「大量の画像を自動的に」ではなく、「ある画像を個別に」とかであればPhotoshopでいいでしょうし。

Comment: 言語はPythonかC++だと都合がいいです。画像はhttp://www.intechopen.com/books/new-approaches-to-characterization-and-recognition-of-faces/real-time-video-face-recognition-for-embedded-devicesからの引用です。用途としては大量の画像を自動的に処理することが目的です。

Comment: @user20244 追加情報は特定の人でしか気づかないコメントに書くのではなく質問文に編集・追記する形で記載し、追記した旨を伝えたい場合はコメントで追記した旨をお知らせ下さい。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。追記しました。